# angular ng build --prod does not keep the name of the class (MyClass.constructor.name)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

When compiling in angular 7 production mode I can't keep the class names. I tried the different parameters of the Terser plugin but none of them solve this problem.
Is there a solution for this problem? Or is there another alternative to MyClass.constructor.name.

Thank you in advance

Below the custom Webpack configuration

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                parallel: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    keep_classnames: true,
                    mangle: false
                }
            })
        ]
    }
};
```

- @angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.1.1"
- @angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.2"
- @angular/cli": "^7.0.4",

Answer (score 1):

As any other optimized Javascript code, an Angular app in production mode goes through a minification process that changes all classes, functions and variables names to minimal ones (usually one letter) in order to reduce the loaded bundle size. So you can't rely on the `MyClass.constructor.name` and compare it to a static value.

Comment: there is however an option to keep the class names during the minification. I need the class name because I save classes in the local storage which are therefore stringified. Now I need to reinstantiate them later but for that I need to know the name of the class.

Comment: have you tested that your configuration is taken in account? From what I know webpack cannot be tuned when using the CLI for the build.

Comment: Yes I added the option to hide console messages (console.*) in the code and this option works correctly.

Comment: anyone have find a solution?

Comment: @DavideBoldrin the clean alternative to `MyClass.constructor.name` is `myVar instanceof MyClass`

Comment: i have a class "data-table" it is estended from another component.
inside data-table i have to check constructor.name but it dosn't work in production mode. i can't init  a new Component because new Circular dependecy detected appear @GuerricP